# Spring-Security : OAuth2 Set roles in user object before it is stored in the security context

Tags: java, spring-security

The goal is to manipulate the roles of a user(or simply create a new Authentication object since I'v got a hunch they cant be manipulated directly) before its stored in the context. After a lot of digging I found that the authentication is perfomred in the **OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication** and later stored using a **sessionStrategy**.

The part where I am stuck at is telling spring to use/override that filter.

So far I have managed to create a **CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter** extending the original one.

I tried to instantiate the filter and add it to the filter chane like so.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/callback/**", "/resources/**", "/static/**", "/webjars/**", "/webjar/**", "/error**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().addFilterAt(createCustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                ;
    }

    private CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter createCustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(){
        OAuth2SsoProperties sso = (OAuth2SsoProperties)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(OAuth2SsoProperties.class);
        OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = ((UserInfoRestTemplateFactory)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(UserInfoRestTemplateFactory.class)).getUserInfoRestTemplate();
        ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices = (ResourceServerTokenServices)this.getApplicationContext().getBean(ResourceServerTokenServices.class);
        CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter customFilter=new CustomOAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(sso.getLoginPath());
        customFilter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        customFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        customFilter.setApplicationEventPublisher(this.getApplicationContext());
        return customFilter;
    }
```

but that, as expected, just calls both filters- mine and the default one.

**Is there a way to "replace" the original filter functionality without creating serious issues and save the ability to later use the @Secured anotation for example, in order to secure application endpoints ?**

I'v read about using postProcessor in the configuration but never found an extensive well expleined answer.I'v also read about custom configuration classes but not for OAuth2 . Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: First of all, ouauth2 does not contain any roles. with a token are a set of claims, and when you access rhe /userInfo endpoint using your token you map your roles using a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper i suggest you read up on how oauth2 actually works, and read the entire oauth2-section in the spring reference before you decide on writing potentially dangerous custom security code. You should NOT manipulate filters.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you very much for your coment. They(upper levels) explicitly require from me to implement this functionality without putting the roles in the token and specified that the roles must be loaded from a seperate source and stored with the user in the session if possible, thats why I never questioned it in my mind-its seems they want it this way explicitly. Will a custom GrantedAuthoritiesMapper work for the purpose ?

Comment: oauth2 is a specification, with strict implementation rules. A token does NOT contain any types of roles. So what you are writing makes no senses. As i have already written, i suggest that you read up on what oauth2 is, and understand how it works before asking on stack overflow as your question in its current form does not make any type of sense. It is clear that ”they” have no clue what they are talking about either.